# Symfony 5 Cache Component AWS elasticache invalid DSN

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, redis, amazon-elasticache

Since there wasn't any related post, has anybody occured, when using symfony cache component and using AWS ElasitCache Redis clusters, when using the provided endpoint has occured this kind of error:

```
the option "dsn" with value "{redis-dsn}" is invalid
```

dsn: **redis://{aws-redis-uri}:6379**

cache.yaml looks like this:

```
framework:
cache:
    pools:
        status.cache:
            adapter: cache.app

        redis.cache:
            adapter: cache.adapter.redis
            provider: '%env(REDIS_URL)%'
```

the action that invokes the error:

```
  $client = RedisAdapter::createConnection(
            $_ENV['REDIS_URL'],
            [
                'timeout'       => 3,
                'persistent'    => 1,
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Could you try to url encode "{aws-redis-uri}" in the dsn?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, it wasn't related with this issue. But to be sure predis extension has to be installed.